# Excel VBA Insert row in table when filtered

Tags: vba, excel

I have researched a lot for this answer but I cant find one. I have a feeling the solution might be easy but it is eluding me.

I have a table, and there is a column where the user writes down the amount of rows he wants to insert (the inserted rows will be exactly the same as the one the active cell is, where the change occurred).

```
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

xValue = Target.Value - 1

Set KeyCells = Intersect(Target.EntireRow, tbl.DataBodyRange)

Sheets("Orders").Unprotect Password:=Password
Application.EnableEvents = False
With KeyCells
    On Error GoTo WrongShift
    .Copy
    .Offset(1).Resize(xValue).Insert
End With
```

The code above inserts rows like the one where the Target change occurred, but it stops working when it tries to insert rows in a filtered table. Error 1004, insert method of class range failed. My sheet has protection, but I clearly unprotect it first.

What must I do to make this work? If you need more code or more input from me please let me know. And excuse my ignorance please...

Comment: remove the filter and then insert.

Comment: Thanks, but I can’t do that. The table has 51 columns and users will be filtering a lot, they will crucify me if I take off their 10+ filters. Is there really not any way of doing this? I don’t mind if the new rows are left hidden.

Comment: Iterate the filters, store them, remove them, insert, reinstate the filters.

Comment: "stops working", as in, you're getting a runtime error?

Comment: yes, a run time error. Edited my question with it. And about iterating the filters, I have seen the code but for what I have seen it doesnt work that well with dates, and my users can filter columns with dates. Like I said, I don't mind if the rows are left hidden.